# Android Location Manager in Service

Tags: java, android, service, location

I have tried create a IntentService, but then I've read about it on Internet that I should be using a Service instead. I don't actually know what I do wrong on the code. Can somebody explain me a little bit?

I'm trying to create a simple Service that reads latitude and longitude even if application is swiped away from a screen and finally POST them to my custom created API. It seems that the App crash on Location Manager in GPSTracker.java

GPSTracker.java

```
package YOU.SOLD.YOUR.SOUL;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

    LocationManager LM;

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        LM.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 1, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

    }
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package YOU.SOLD.YOUR.SOUL;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int PERMISSION_1 = 1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_1);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, GPSTracker.class);
        startService(intent);
    }
}
```

Permissions added to Manifest is COARSE and FINE location. Also service has been added as .GPSTracker

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create service YOU.SOLD.YOUR.SOUL.GPSTracker: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String, long, float, android.location.LocationListener)' on a null object reference

and

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.location.LocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(java.lang.String, long, float, android.location.LocationListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: You will need to initialize your LocationManager reference: https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/training/basics/location/locationmanager.html

Comment: I'm literally an idiot. I had correct code before, but I had some other issue which made me rewrite code and I reproduced a new issue. Very much thank you. I would like to mark your comment as answer so would you like to write it as answer so I can do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to fix the NullPointerException, just initialize the LocationManager reference.
Also, move the logic to request location updates to the `onStartCommand()` method override, and return `START_STICKY` in order to restart the service automatically.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        LocationManager locationManager =
        (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 1, this);
    }

    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I didn't knew about Service.START_STICKY. This lighten me up!